# Generating o/p in WordTemplate as well as in SSRS at the same time

Tags: ssrs-2008, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have written a separate class where I pass calculated values as parameter to generate data in Word template.   I just need to initialize the class(Word template) objects from my DP class `processReport()` and get the word template and ssrs report at the same time.     I am facing errors while executing. Kindly suggest on how to overcome this problem.    The WordTemplate Class seems to runon the client side while the process report is on the server side.
[image: Code in process Report] 
[image: The Error message. I dont get errors when I try to execute the <code>processReport()</code> through job(for testing)]

The Error message. I dont get the same error when I try to execute the `processReport()` through job(for testing) may be because job runs on client

Comment: Can you provide some more details please? What errors are you receiving and can you put in some code so we can see what is going on in there?

Comment: I did a work around to achieve the result. The word Template, i have done it in the controller class.